Smoothness of complex analytic subspaces
Say I have a complex analytic subspace $X$ of a complex manifold. Additionally:

$X$ is a topological manifold, and
For each $x \in X$, the set of derivatives at $x$ of smooth paths holomorphic discs in $X$ that go through $x$ is a complex subspace of dimension dim $X$.

Must $X$ be a complex submanifold?

I believe a cuspidal plane curve is a counterexample.

@JasonStarr I'm not so sure you can get smooth paths with non-zero derivative at the cusp. But in any case, I edited the question to show I'm happy to use holomorphic discs instead of smooth paths.

By smooth paths I understood “C-infinity” paths, i.e., paths in the smooth category.

Yes, that is what I originally meant. I changed the question to simplify the resolution of this issue, but I was saying that even with C-infinity paths I'm doubtful a cuspidal plane curve is a counterexample, because of the second condition. Do you still believe it is? Can you prove there are enough smooth curves going through the cusp with non-zero derivative at the cusp?
